# Cutting out triangles and mixing them

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Hi could you please give me any tips on how to cut 4 triangles out of an image and mix them together, so that they look like this:

[image]

I want to use a python in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this image (`dog.jpg`):

[image]

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Open image, generate a copy and rotate copy 180 degrees
im1 = Image.open('dog.jpg')
im2 = im1.copy().rotate(180)
# DEBUG: im2.save('im2.png')

# Get dimensions of image
w, h = im1.size

# Create an alpha layer same size as our image filled with black
alpha = Image.new('L',(w,h))

# Draw 2 white (i.e. transparent) triangles on the alpha layer
draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
draw.polygon([(0, 0), (w, 0), (w/2, h/2)], fill = (255))
draw.polygon([(0, h), (w, h), (w/2, h/2)], fill = (255))
# DEBUG: alpha.save('alpha.png')

# Composite rotated image over initial image while respecting alpha
result = Image.composite(im1, im2, alpha)
result.save('result.png')
```

[image]

The intermediate steps (commented with `#DEBUG:` in the code), look like this:

`im2.png`

[image]

and `alpha.png`:

[image]